# execute a javascript function when user selects a file

Tags: javascript, file, input

In an html page ,I am adding an input element.

```
<input type="file" name="fileselect" id="fselect"> </input>
```

I wanted to execute a javascript function ,when a user selects a file.Suppose I want to write to the console too.

Is `jquery select()` the correct function to check if user has selected a file? I tried like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#fselect').select(function(){ 
      console.log('selected');
      myfun(); 
    });
});

function myfun(){
   alert('you selected a file');
}
```

For some reason, when I select a file using the input element,nothing is written to console and no alert box appears..Is the `select()` call coded wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event you want is *change*, not *select*.

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/select/):

> The select event is sent to an element when the user makes a text selection inside it.

And for [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes

Answer (score 3):

You can use `change` event:

```
​$("#fselect").change(function() {
    // do something
});​​​​​​​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BtsHL/

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#fselect').change(function(){ 
      console.log('selected');
    });
});
```